# How to display dropdown list depends on the another dropdown option in joomla 3.x

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I am new to joomla 3,Creating a custom Joomla component. I want to display the product drodown list item based on the product category dropdown list item in admin side. All data loaded from DB..I have knowledge to do it core php but i didn't have idea in joomla 3.

How can I create the custom field type for the product category list and product list, how i called the ajax function when product category list item is changed

I didn't have idea how we call the ajax file using jquery when the product category list item is changed..

For Example:

```
<b>Please Product catgory</b><br/>
<select name="productcat" id="productcat">
        <option value="">Select category</option>
        <option value="1">productcategory1</option>
        <option value="2">productcategory2</option>
        <option value="3">productcategory3</option>
</select>
```

If productcategory1 selected then i want to display product dropdown items depends productcategory1 like wise:

```
<select name="product" id="product">
        <option value="">choose product</option>
        <option value="1">product1</option>
        <option value="2">product2</option>
        <option value="3">product3</option>
</select>
```

Please any one tell the solution for it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided the jQuery Solution

```
      $('select#two').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('select#one').change(function() {

     $('select#two').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/xGJRP/15/)**

Comment: this is a `change` function. the OP requires it to depend on the option selected ;)

Comment: i need to pass the product cat id through ajax and get the dynamic product value form db for the product dropdown box

Comment: @peter Thank u.. :) i have more than 50 category and each category have more than 100 product.. so i want know how we call ajax file in joomla 3 exctly like this but i want to fetch the data from db using **ajax** [http://jsfiddle.net/bbAU9/]

Comment: @anitha plz have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383822/how-to-change-select-list-from-another-using-ajax-in-joomla

Comment: @peter Thanks for the link.. It's exactly same as my requirement.. It will surely help to solve my issue :)

Comment: @Anitha whose peter in this conversation??

Comment: can u tell whose peter first??

Comment: oh sorry before ur profile name not showed..@peter or @PeterSmith it shown in help tips I thought it bring ur profile name.. am extremely sorry am new to stock overflow also

Comment: Thanks for the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383822/how-to-change-select-list-from-another-using-ajax-in-joomla) I solved it :)